# count occurrences of phrases in a python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, count

I have a df like this:

```
names = ["Internal medicine, Gastroenterology", "Internal medicine, Family and general medicine, Endocrinology", "Pediatrics, Medical genetics, Laboratory medicine", "Internal medicine"]
df = pd.DataFrame(names, columns=['names'])
```

I would like to know how often each medical term occurs. e.g. here

- Internal medicine: 3
- Gastroenterology: 1
- etc

It works with `Counter` for words but how do I get it working for phrases such as "Internal medicine"? The ", " separates the phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` by `,` and then `explode` and then `value_counts`

```
df['names'].str.split(", ").explode().value_counts()
```

Comment: should be split(", ") otherwise it miscounts but thanks otherwise great!! accepting in 5 min

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [`collections.Counter`](https://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html), you can do this:

```
In [1945]: from collections import Counter

In [1946]: d = Counter(df['names'].str.split(", ").explode().tolist())

In [1947]: d
Out[1947]: 
Counter({'Internal medicine': 3,
         'Gastroenterology': 1,
         'Family and general medicine': 1,
         'Endocrinology': 1,
         'Pediatrics': 1,
         'Medical genetics': 1,
         'Laboratory medicine': 1})
```